# dropdown-menu with jquery 1.11.0 and bootstrap 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to fix a problem in one website about dropdown menu with jquery 1.11.0 and bootstrap 3.3.1.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse navStyle">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu01" class="scroll-link">menu 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu02" class="scroll-link">menu 02</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">O que fazemos<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#oqueFazemos">submenu 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#oqueFazemos">submenu 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#oqueFazemos">submenu 03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#menu03" class="scroll-link">Menu 03</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu04" class="scroll-link">Menu 04</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `</li>` at menu item 02. I fixed it and the indentation, and the dropdown for OqueFrazemos is working in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your help UnstableEagle. Unfortunately, I believe this site has more problems than it we can see. I hate "help" sites that I didn't made. I tryed even fire a javascript and didn't work..... (if you wanna see the full site -> anapalu.com.br/_index.html - code commented....)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was a css display:inline-block missing :)